# Litecoin - same transaction hash and block hash

Tags: bitcoin-core, litecoin

After building litecoin v0.15.1rc1 client on Ubuntu 16.04 I wanted to build an app that uses Litecoin. But I stumbled upon something odd (at least to me).

I did the following command: `./litecoin-cli getrawtransaction 716aba3806b7737f5152af0079c73d20b924a4c1b679026feac42205e06d9f5b 1`

I saw that transaction hash and block hash are absolutely the same. Can someone explain this? I can paste the whole output if requested.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: this transaction is a testnet transaction

Full output:

```
{
  "txid": "716aba3806b7737f5152af0079c73d20b924a4c1b679026feac42205e06d9f5b",
  "hash": "716aba3806b7737f5152af0079c73d20b924a4c1b679026feac42205e06d9f5b",
  "version": 2,
  "size": 667,
  "vsize": 667,
  "locktime": 482836,
  "vin": [
    {
      "txid": "c7fdc7179381c001b056e2f905c5b506c79d10ae9fc3cd2a7721467a4bf05906",
      "vout": 1,
      "scriptSig": {
        "asm": "3045022100d723c11024ec3800aa87f9e20ebbd344ebcb57db5f71b2cc66155a2ea3ac167f022019f1455f1438d44e048ecf3895a5e3d041b2aca1146fc18b9c8dc4e77e40bb50[ALL] 035e23a55d8804ae49e49136a2412fb53b02f3de495622ef1e6a40f63f1ea93e44",
        "hex": "483045022100d723c11024ec3800aa87f9e20ebbd344ebcb57db5f71b2cc66155a2ea3ac167f022019f1455f1438d44e048ecf3895a5e3d041b2aca1146fc18b9c8dc4e77e40bb500121035e23a55d8804ae49e49136a2412fb53b02f3de495622ef1e6a40f63f1ea93e44"
      },
      "sequence": 4294967294
    },
    {
      "txid": "102313318e90c4c4ccb7581c90c1a8d38085106f19917544a21359067a80096a",
      "vout": 1,
      "scriptSig": {
        "asm": "30440220269bf280fd82163658da1be2f5301f851f13978937ee2c7701f654ac49ffc03602204fafb6592af7bdbedede204bd476b24fb03b50cdd75c5fbdb35e57692e870635[ALL] 0258c857eff89b9b54ccab29d4fcbadcb01c0a4cf9627fa56e4d6b96ae74f5e462",
        "hex": "4730440220269bf280fd82163658da1be2f5301f851f13978937ee2c7701f654ac49ffc03602204fafb6592af7bdbedede204bd476b24fb03b50cdd75c5fbdb35e57692e87063501210258c857eff89b9b54ccab29d4fcbadcb01c0a4cf9627fa56e4d6b96ae74f5e462"
      },
      "sequence": 4294967294
    },
    {
      "txid": "7c7c64412dfaad8bf74280748f295ae8b4fa88b469e2473b08c98198c1ba9266",
      "vout": 0,
      "scriptSig": {
        "asm": "3044022039293b68bda763f2f07ead2edd257eee35078ece91e0afdeb56b898c5e89d44502205f49dbebb0521e1cf4d74a1ec0fec0d174352e47385f773c4323e0533453e566[ALL] 035e23a55d8804ae49e49136a2412fb53b02f3de495622ef1e6a40f63f1ea93e44",
        "hex": "473044022039293b68bda763f2f07ead2edd257eee35078ece91e0afdeb56b898c5e89d44502205f49dbebb0521e1cf4d74a1ec0fec0d174352e47385f773c4323e0533453e5660121035e23a55d8804ae49e49136a2412fb53b02f3de495622ef1e6a40f63f1ea93e44"
      },
      "sequence": 4294967294
    },
    {
      "txid": "7c7c64412dfaad8bf74280748f295ae8b4fa88b469e2473b08c98198c1ba9266",
      "vout": 1,
      "scriptSig": {
        "asm": "304402200563b82f8d85ebc37f0adc106595caff6a69e5fecfda67c3003523fc195dd2a4022023f18ab2027f39b8c1e6be8cdf57d5fb6aae56c71756db4db9f123d6e88b77d3[ALL] 0209fac8d3f346aef9bf636e3d539e9c2cb0eb59bcd2898d560f0bbc9405628067",
        "hex": "47304402200563b82f8d85ebc37f0adc106595caff6a69e5fecfda67c3003523fc195dd2a4022023f18ab2027f39b8c1e6be8cdf57d5fb6aae56c71756db4db9f123d6e88b77d301210209fac8d3f346aef9bf636e3d539e9c2cb0eb59bcd2898d560f0bbc9405628067"
      },
      "sequence": 4294967294
    }
  ],
  "vout": [
    {
      "value": 0.01885081,
      "n": 0,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 6e3201e86a59653a0ea031af8f2b03615748d248 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
        "hex": "76a9146e3201e86a59653a0ea031af8f2b03615748d24888ac",
        "reqSigs": 1,
        "type": "pubkeyhash",
        "addresses": [
          "mqZcXjXjHBTHJwSxns2ZajLHpu3Ej33gh3"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "value": 0.10000000,
      "n": 1,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 b3ebe3b4f7f100e00a1abfbb4ae39af4aece27f3 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
        "hex": "76a914b3ebe3b4f7f100e00a1abfbb4ae39af4aece27f388ac",
        "reqSigs": 1,
        "type": "pubkeyhash",
        "addresses": [
          "mwvHqHCSHqrfp7t7bnFA74JdnmaFAVXpLk"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "hex": "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",
  "blockhash": "bb55f8d0463ddf6b1c854286a2f1911ab590ed154ef502406f28fd0a01e52238",
  "confirmations": 6,
  "time": 1523009113,
  "blocktime": 1523009113
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're on the right chain? I don't see a tx or block for `716aba3806b7737f5152af0079c73d20b924a4c1b679026feac42205e06d9f5b` on the litecoin chain

Comment: @RaghavSood its on the testnet, sorry i forgot to mention that

Comment: Can you post the full output? Looking at https://chain.so/tx/LTCTEST/716aba3806b7737f5152af0079c73d20b924a4c1b679026feac42205e06d9f5b, it looks like the transaction hash and the block hash are different.

Comment: @AndrewChow i know that chain.so gives different hashes, i will paste it here asap

Comment: @AndrewChow https://pastebin.com/JHU640YT This is the output that litecoin client gives me

Comment: @Micic The txid and blockhash are clearly different: `"txid": "716aba3806b7737f5152af0079c73d20b924a4c1b679026feac42205e06d9f5b",` `"blockhash": "bb55f8d0463ddf6b1c854286a2f1911ab590ed154ef502406f28fd0a01e52238",`. Are you confusing `hash` for `blockchash`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The txid and blockhash are clearly different. It appears that you are confusing the `hash` field for the `blockchash` field. The `hash` field is still just the hash of the transaction, not the hash of the block containing the transaction. Since this transaction is not a segwit transaction, the `hash` and `txid` will be the same. If this transaction were segwit (i.e. contains a segwit input), then the `hash` will be different from the `txid`.

Comment: so in conclusion, txid and hash keys are absolutely the same thing? and my pastebin is a correct output?

Comment: They are not always the same thing, but in this case they are the same thing. The output of the command is correct.

Comment: sorry for bothering you further, but shouldn't  **txid** represent the transaction hash, and **hash** represent the hash of the block?

Comment: I reread the answer and get it now, sorry for additional questions. Thank you!